# Deleting objects from associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am learning Rails and I am reading the Beginning Rails 3 book. When you have a `has_many` association you automatically receives methods.

Let say user has many articles.

```
user.articles.delete(article)
```

Now that line only set the foreign key of the article to "NULL". Is it correct that you also must destroy/delete the article if you want it to disappear from the database, or is there a method that does it both?

And what happens if you destroy an article that is in a relationship with a user before you delete the association?

Answer (score 2):

There are some difference between `delete` and `destroy`.

The delete method essentially deletes a row.. that's it..

On the other hand, `destroy` allows you more options:

- it will check any callbacks such as before_delete, or any dependencies specified on the model.
- it will also keep the object that just got deleted in memory; So it allows you to leave a message saying for example: “Article #{article.id} deleted!!”
- And the answer for your question: it will delete any child objects associated with the object.

So, instead of

```
user.articles.delete(article)
```

you can use

```
user.articles.destroy(article)
```

In this way you will prevent any orphaned rows on the database.

Comment: What does this have to do with REST?

Comment: @Beerlington - you are right, there is no relation between routes and the method delete. I will edit the answer...